# cast content from local (mobile or PC) device

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

From the main picture on this page:  https://developers.google.com/cast/

And the description of Sender app on this page:  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist#cast-basics

Sender app / device (e.g. YouTube app on mobile)
The sender initiates connecting to and / or casting (sending a content link) to a Google Cast Ready receiver (a.k.a Cast receiver) on the same Wi-Fi network.

Question:  Can I cast media that is stored on my local device (a mobile or PC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you write your own sender and provide a tiny web server in your sender to serve the content to the html receiver.

Comment: Upon further testing, I discovered that if I run my app (iOS) on a Xcode simulator then it works fine to cast content locally.  But if the app was executed from a real iDevice, then it does not cast local content.  Keep in mind, in iOS framework has two separate code: i386 and ARM.  My suspicion is that the framework for ARM blocks casting content from local device.  Am I wrong?

Comment: One more piece of info:  Running the app on one iDevice but the content comes from another iDevice, then it also works fine.

Comment: You can just point your browser at the URL of the media served from your iOS device and see if it plays or not; if it does, then you need to check on how you are passing the url to your receiver (use chrome debugger on port 9222 after whitelisting your chromecast device); if it doesn't play, then your embedded web server is not working properly and you need to address that.

Comment: oops!  user error, I forgot to change the IP address.  Thanks for your help.